# Using function from popup form in existing first form

Tags: c#, winforms, function

I'm having trouble figuring out how to properly do this.

The basics is that i have 1 form which is used to fill out all kinds of data which i save in 2 lists. The 2nd form is one that is called via a menu option which displays an overview of all the current data. it is opened like so:

```
private void OpenOverviewForm()
{
    Overview formOverview = new Overview();

    for (int i = 0; i < callListNL.Count; i++)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(callListNL[i].Opco);
        item.SubItems.Add(callListNL[i].UserID);
        item.SubItems.Add(callListNL[i].Email);
        item.SubItems.Add(callListNL[i].Title);
        formOverview.listView1Overview.Items.Add(item);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < callListPL.Count; i++)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(callListPL[i].Opco);
        item.SubItems.Add(callListPL[i].UserID);
        item.SubItems.Add(callListPL[i].Email);
        item.SubItems.Add(callListPL[i].Title);
        formOverview.listView1Overview.Items.Add(item);
    }
    formOverview.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    formOverview.Show();
}
```

In this new form, there is a listview with a list of all saved logs. And what i want is for the endusers to be able to doubleclick one of the entries, which will then close the 2nd form and display the data that they've selected on the first form. In order to do that, i need to be able to use the doubleclick event of the listview to provide the index of the item that they've doubleclicked to one of my functions that exist in the first form. However i can't find a way to get my function from Form1 recognised in my Form2.

I know it's possible with the following:

```
public partial class Overview : Form
{
    public Overview()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void listView1Overview_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Form1 newform = new Form1();
        newform.OverviewFormDisplay(listView1Overview.SelectedIndices[0]);

    }
}
```

But as this code actually creates a completely new instance of my original form, i don't think that this is useable. Or am i wrong?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a variable of your main form instance
and add constructor of `Overview` with reference of `Form1` as parameter

```
public partial class Overview : Form
{
    private Form1 _mainForm;

    public Overview(Form1 mainform) : this()
    {
        this._mainForm = mainForm;
    }

    private void listView1Overview_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this._mainForm.OverviewFormDisplay(listView1Overview.SelectedIndices[0]);
    }
}
```

Then you can use all `public` properties and methods of `Form1` instance inside your `Overview` form

When creating instance of `Overview` form, pass reference of main form to constructor

```
//.....this line must be in the Form1
Overview formOverview = new Overview(this);
//....
```

Comment: I still lack too much C# experience to properly follow your advice.
My initial form is automatically created by visual studio using
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

I'm inexperienced with creating extra instances of these forms to work with.

Where can i implement the first part of the code you've mentioned?

Comment: Try to copy/paste code to the your code of Overview class (Overview.cs). And then you can play with properties/methods of main form from `Overview` form

Comment: Hey Fabio, Thank you for your edit. I was doing it right after all. However the this() in line public Overview(Form1 mainForm) : this()
is being underlined and cannot be executed with error "Overview does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments".

Am i doing something wrong with this?

Comment: Do not delete default constructor `public Overview(){InitializeComponent();}`

Comment: Ah, of course, dumb of me. Well, i'm very excited to say that it is working now. Unfortunately i don't fully understand how it works, but it works. Thanks for your quick help!

Answer (score 0):

You can also resolve this with creating a Property to your Overview form:

```
public partial class Overview : Form
{
    public Overview()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private ListViewItem lvi;
    public ListViewItem SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return lvi;
        }
        set
        {
            lvi = value;
        }
    }

    private void listView1Overview_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedItem = listView1Overview.SelectedItems[0];
        Close();
    }
}
```

And you have to edit your code that creates formOverview to look like this:

```
private void OpenOverviewForm()
{
    Overview formOverview = new Overview();

    for (int i = 0; i < callListNL.Count; i++)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(callListNL[i].Opco);
        item.SubItems.Add(callListNL[i].UserID);
        item.SubItems.Add(callListNL[i].Email);
        item.SubItems.Add(callListNL[i].Title);
        formOverview.listView1Overview.Items.Add(item);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < callListPL.Count; i++)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(callListPL[i].Opco);
        item.SubItems.Add(callListPL[i].UserID);
        item.SubItems.Add(callListPL[i].Email);
        item.SubItems.Add(callListPL[i].Title);
        formOverview.listView1Overview.Items.Add(item);
    }
    formOverview.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    formOverview.ShowDialog();
    if (formOverview.SelectedItem != null)//just in case the user closes formOverview without double-clicking any item
    {
        OverviewFormDisplay(formOverview.SelectedItem);
    }
}
```

Well probably this is not the best way to do this if you don't want your formOverview to close every time the user double-clicks an item to execute those functions you wanted, but it does the work. Hopefully helps :)